# The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented **Web API Controller** with `PUT` method (I marked method with HttpPut attribute from `System.Web.Http`).

And when I try to make put request, i have message

> The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.

I remove webdav in `Web.Config`, added put etc.
But it is still not work.
How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the param names on your URL match with some param names in your controller method declaration. This simple mistake can cause 405.